# Filter django objects based number of foreign references

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, django-models

I have an object that represents a list of items. Each item has a foreign key to this list.

```
class ItemList(Model):
    pass

class Item(Model):
    list = ForeignKey(ItemList, related_name="items")
```

I'm wanting to fetch ItemLists that contain items. Is there any way to do this in django, or am I going to have to manually remove them from the results of the query?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out I was able to do it via annotate and exclude:

```
ItemList.objects.annotate(num_items=Count('items')).exclude(num_items=0)
```